# Issue trying to use a template object inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, most-vexing-parse

Consider the following class definitions ...

Node

```
    template <class T> class Node {
        private :
            T* data;
            Node<T>* next;
        public :
            Node(T* data);
            void setData(T* data);
            T* getData();
            void setNext(Node<T>* next);
            Node<T>* getNext();
    };
```

Linked List

```
    template <class T> class LinkedList {
        private :
            Node<T>* start;
        public :
            LinkedList();
            void add(Node<T>* node);
            bool isEmpty();
    };
```

Main

```
    #include "Foo.h"
    int main() {
        Foo foo();
        Node<Foo> node(&foo);
        LinkedList<Foo> linkedList();
        linkedList.add(&node);
        return 0;
    }
```

When it is compiled it throws the following error...

```
    Request for member 'add' in 'linkedList', which is of non-class type 'LinkedList<Foo>()'
```

I am quite inexperienced making use of templates, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing to do with template, but with most-vexing-parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo foo();` and `LinkedList<Foo> linkedList();` are not variables but are function prototypes.

Please use `Foo foo;` and `LinkedList<Foo> linkedList;` instead.

You can also use `Foo foo = Foo();` and `LinkedList<Foo> linkedList = LinkedList<Foo>();` to make it clear that the constructors are called.

Comment: Excuse me, what would happen in a scenario where Foo class has a constructor with at least an argument? Sorry if my question is silly, but I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: For calling constructors with an argument or more, you can use `Foo foo(arguments);`

Comment: I am really grateful, I learned OOP with Java and there are several noticeable differences while using generics.

Comment: `Foo foo{};` is an other alternative since C++11.